# Android 4.4. under VirtualBox cannot access to ACR122U reader

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I use Android 4.4 running under VirtualBox with an ACR122U NFC reader connected.

I have add a few rows to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

And:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And try to check NFC reader by

```
nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if(nfcAdapter == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NFC NOT supported on this devices!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But receive message that NFC is NOT supported. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: To be sure, you plug a NFC reader to your PC and want your emulator use it as Android NFC reader ?

Comment: As Michael already said, ACS readers aren't supported natively by Android and Android-x86, which you're using. But you may work with ACR122U with the help of the following tools by Thomas Skjølberg: [ACR 122 USB NFC Reader Utils](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skjolberg.acr122u&hl=en) and [External NFC Reader Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skjolberg.nfc.external&hl=en). You will need to adapt your codes to get it working with [External NFC Service API](https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api) instead of Android NFC API. Regarding to the nativ

Answer (score 0):

The Android NFC stack does not support the ACR122U reader out of the box. And actually, I doubt that you would be able to write a driver layer for the NFC stack that could make use of that reader since it only supports a subset of the functionality of current NFC controllers in Android devices and since the PN532 NFC chip in the ACR122U speaks a completely different protocol as compared to current NFC controllers (which speak NCI).